# How to write tests for multithreaded code execution time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have  a multi-threaded code which processes a list of jobs with a ExecutorService and some threads inside.I want to write a test case that ensures it takes under a certain time.The problem is, this code works completely asynchronous so simply doing end-start won't do any good.

How can I approach this problem ?

Comment: You need to give a bit more focus to this question. What exact do you want to test? What does the code look like? What is the time limit? How many threads?

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MultiThreadedTest {
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private Callable<Boolean> getCallable(Long sleepMillis) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void pass() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(getCallable(1000L));
        Assert.assertTrue(future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    }

    @Test
    public void fail() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(getCallable(3000L));
        Assert.assertTrue(future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    }

    @Test
    public void failCheck() {
        Assert.assertThrows(TimeoutException.class, () -> {
            Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(getCallable(3000L));
            Assert.assertTrue(future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs asynchronously, your tester should be asynchronous too. Can you check if the jobs have finished, by any means? If so, the tester must run and check the jobs status periodically (every minute, for example), but it should not endure over a predetermined timeout - in case any of the asynchronous jobs get hanged.